# How to deal with big JQueryUI autocomplete response?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

In my application, the JQueryUI autocomplete source is a very large set. When I bind the source to a text box, the big list runs through the entire page when many items match the users input. Is there a way of adding a scroll bar to the suggested list? Currently, I am limiting the response on the server to 20 items. But, that will make life hard for our users.

By the way, I am dynamically building the auto suggest list, calling the server each time a user enters a new character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim the result up to 20-30 results and wait when user will put next letter to filter search results better.

It's not a good practice to have very big autocomplete list because you will loose a lot of performance and all advantages of autocomplete will disappear.

Comment: I think with good logic, you can overcome the performance loss. How is trimming the list a good idea when all it does is misrepresent to the user the selection choices. Maybe instead require at least 3 characters be typed before kicking in the auto complete. I can return a list well over 3k in well under one second, maybe (200-300ms)